# What is a Skyshard? What is a Sky Crystal?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I've found a Skyshard while doing Golden Lotus dailies in the Vale of Eternal Blossom:

[image: Skyshard]

What is a Sky Crystal and what is it for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building and using a Sky Crystal allows you to fight [Alani the Stormborn](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=64403), who is a rare spawn cruising around in the sky above the Vale of Eternal Blossom. Like the [Time-Lost Proto Drake](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=32491) or [Aeonaxx](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=50062), Alani drops a mount when killed: in this case, the [Thundering Ruby Cloud Serpent](http://www.wowhead.com/item=90655). She seems to respawn pretty fast, so the only hard part here is collecting enough Skyshards.

Source: [Wowhead](http://www.wowhead.com/item=86546#comments)